# Spark-Kafka Integration | spark-submit giving errors |

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have written a program in Python for reading data(`spark.readStream`) from `kafkatopic` and writing it into
a parquet file. While submitting the program I'm receiving **classNotFound** error even though I have mentioned all the jars required and every jar has been added properly.

This is the code I have written:
[image: This is the code I have written]
[The error which I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiXJj.png)

Comment: Please clarify which class is missing and add code / errors as text, not images

Comment: please add exception details in your question

Comment: I'm really sorry I cant do a copy paste of query /error, because the environment is copy-paste disabled, I'll be updating the question with the error.